# Program crashes after call to push_back() for vector of pointers despite previous ok usage

Tags: c++

I have a situation where i'm creating objects with new and storing a pointer to these objects in a vector. I later copy the pointer across to another vector and delete it from the original vector. In a seperate test program I have been able to do this with no trouble at all.

When added to a larger program I end up with a crash (the callstack at crash is added below). I've been unable to diagnose the problem so far, and have verified that all the pointers used lead to a valid memory location.

Where the vectors of are of the form

```
std::vector<Node*> openSet;
std::vector<Node*> closedSet;
```

Node is defined thusly

```
struct Node
{
    Node(sf::Vector2f &tilenode, Node *parentnode)
    {
        nodeposition = tilenode;
        parenttile = parentnode;
        gcost = 0;
    }

    sf::Vector2f nodeposition;
    Node *parenttile;
    float gcost;
};
```

The function's that cause the crash are:

```
void Pather::CreateNode(Node* node, string whichvec)
{
    if (whichvec == "openSet")
    {
        openSet.push_back(node);
    }
    else if (whichvec == "closedSet")
    {
        closedSet.push_back(node);
    }
}

void Pather::AddNode(sf::Vector2f thenode, Node *parentnode, string whichvec) 
{
    CreateNode(new Node(thenode, parentnode), whichvec);
}
```

Specifically the crash always happens at a call to openSet.push_back(node); This is called multiple times without problem in the program before the crash occurs.

The code used to copy is along the lines of

```
closedSet.push_back(openset[element]);
openSet.erase(openset.begin()+element-1);
```

The callstack at crash is

```
#0 0x7ffff680aba5   raise(sig=<value optimised out>) (../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64)
#1 0x7ffff680e6b0   abort() (abort.c:92)
#2 0x7ffff684443b   __libc_message(do_abort=<value optimised out>, fmt=<value optimised out>) (../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:189)
#3 (    0x00007ffff684e4b6 in malloc_printerr(action=3, str=0x7ffff6922078 "double free or corruption (out) (malloc.c:6283)
#4 0x7ffff6854c83   __libc_free(mem=<value optimised out>) (malloc.c:3738)
#5 0x403d20 __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Pather::Node*>::deallocate(this=0x721dd0, __p=0x665c70) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/new_allocator.h:95)
#6 0x403c30 std::_Vector_base<Pather::Node*, std::allocator<Pather::Node*> >::_M_deallocate(this=0x721dd0, __p=0x665c70, __n=16) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:146)
#7 0x4080da std::vector<Pather::Node*, std::allocator<Pather::Node*> >::_M_insert_aux(this=0x721dd0, __position=..., __x=@0x7fffffffe490) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:361)
#8 0x407afc std::vector<Pather::Node*, std::allocator<Pather::Node*> >::push_back(this=0x721dd0, __x=@0x7fffffffe490) (/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:741)
#9 0x407616 Pather::CreateNode(this=0x721dd0, node=0xc840c0, whichvec=...) (/home/nova/c++stuff/NewEng/pather.cpp:162)
#10 0x4076ae    Pather::AddNode(this=0x721dd0, thenode=..., parentnode=0xc84000, whichvec=...) (/home/nova/c++stuff/NewEng/pather.cpp:172)
#11 0x407389    Pather::FindPath(this=0x721dd0, stile=4840, ftile=4453) (/home/nova/c++stuff/NewEng/pather.cpp:102)
#12 0x40961b    Player::GetInput(this=0x721c90, window=...) (/home/nova/c++stuff/NewEng/player.cpp:42)
#13 0x403544    Engine::Events(this=0x7202d0) (/home/nova/c++stuff/NewEng/engine.cpp:46)
#14 0x4045fc    main() (/home/nova/c++stuff/NewEng/main.cpp:15)
```

I'm utterly stumped so far. So even a nudge in the right direction would be vastly helpful.

Comment: Your `Node` constructor is probably taking a reference to an object that consequently goes out of scope, or something like that. It'd help to see `Node`'s definition.

Comment: +1 for callstack – but can you try running without optimisations so that the “optimised out” values are shown? Also, I think Tomalak is probably right. This is the most obvious source of error here.

Comment: There are no optimisations included in the compiler options for this program. The only flag it has is debugging symbols. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Just use `shared_ptr`- that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your node copy be:

```
closedSet.push_back(openset[element]);
openSet.erase(openset.begin()+element);
```

In your copy code think about what happens when element is 0. Basically you are not deleting the right node pointer from openSet when copying which will result in both leaked memory and double-freed pointers whenever you delete the nodes.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. I suspect the wider problem is whatever strange thought pattern led me to add that to the code in the first place. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with the code you've shown, but the code you've shown
doesn't do what you describe (copy the pointer from one vector to
another, then delete it in the first).  If by delete it, you mean you
call delete on the pointer, although it is still present in the second
set, you're likely to run into troubles down the road, because you have
a pointer to deleted memory.  Otherwise, crashes in operator new are
usually due to corruption of the free space arena.  Earlier, and in
totally unrelated code.

(Formally, anytime you have a pointer to deleted memory in a container,
even temporarily, it's undefined behavior.  Practically, as long as you
don't dereference the pointer, it won't cause problems.)

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I've added the code used to copy to the post

Comment: You're erasing the wrong element; why the -1.<p> I don't know what you do with the elements afterwards, but that can't be good.  If you're under Linux (the stack trace suggests g++), try running the program under valgrind.

Comment: Thanks, i've no idea why I was erasing like that either i'm afraid (I suspect a moment of idiocy now forgotten). It still crashes, but is a different error that I hope I can track down.

Answer (score 0):

From the callstack you can see

> double free or corruption (out)

So it looks likely that something else is corrupting your memory. My first guess is that some code is double-deleting `Node`s (does `Node` have a destructor you didn't show?).

Comment: The entire definition of node is there, up until the crash the program shouldn't have been deleting anything other than pointers as far as I know.